# Unable to import package NetworkSecurityGroupsOperations of Azure in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-virtual-network

```
From azure.mgmt.network.operations import NetworkSecurityGroupsOperations
ImportError: No module named operations
```

Error in importing submodule operations from this package

Version of the package is: azure-Mgmt-network==2.0.0 rc2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code like below to import NetworkSecurityGroupsOperations:

```
from azure.mgmt.network.v2017_09_01.operations.network_security_groups_operations import NetworkSecurityGroupsOperations
```

You can get more details with this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-network/azure/mgmt/network/v2017_09_01/network_management_client.py) and you can change the **v2017_09_01** with which version you need.